# Jackson case changes in JSON serialization

Tags: java, json, serialization

I'm having some cases where Jackson is changing cases of fields in a POJO during serialization in ways I would not expect. I'm using the following block to do the serialization:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(o)
```

I'm noticing that all of the fields which are prepended with 'v' are getting the next capital letter also lowercased. For example, for the POJO field as below:

```
vStatus1 = "3424522"
```

I see after serialization the following JSON field:

```
vstatus1="3424522"
```

This is mainly important to me because I'm using a switch to go between two different web services which should provide the same output map, but this hiccup is preventing me from doing it cleanly.

Comment: what does your POJO look like? can you post it?

Comment: I'm seeing it as a sent response from a webClient, so I get back a list of the fields inside it as i typed above.

Comment: @Silads this question can not be answered without seeing POJO definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Jackson, you can set the `@JsonProperty` on the field's getter and change it to whatever you like...

```
@JsonProperty("vStatus1")
public String getvStatus1() {
    return vStatus1;
}
// Produces: {"vStatus1":"3424522"}

@JsonProperty("VStatus1")
public String getvStatus1() {
    return vStatus1;
}
// Produces: {"VStatus1":"3424522"}
```

> I'm using a switch to go between two different web services which should provide the same output map

In addition to the above, perhaps consider switching on the lowercased version of your string...

```
switch(myString.toLowerCase()) {
   case "foo": doSomething();
   ...
}
```